# SSRS sorting on a date field containing alphanumerics

Tags: sorting, date, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 3.0, and SharePoint 2013. I am sorting an SSRS report on a date field.  I've used expressions to plug some of the dates as alphanumeric (ie “N/A”, “Ongoing”)  The customer wants the rows sorted by date with the oldest dates first and the “N/A” and the “Ongoing” dates last.  The Sort function is sorting the alphas first, then the other rows that contain dates.  How do I get the Sort expression to sort the dates **oldest to newest** and then sort the “N/A” and “Ongoing” dates last? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a computed sort expression either in the SQL or in the report. I'll give an example of doing it in the report since that's what you asked.

First, go into your group properties and then the Sorting tab. We'll add two sorting conditions. Click the "Add" button and then click the expression button.

For the first condition, we'll separate the dates and the text. So the expression would be something like this:

```
=IIf(IsDate(Fields!MyColumn.Value), 1, 2)
```

Add a second sort condition and set it to sort your column in descending order. This will put the dates first and the text after it.

Comment: @KimFarrell glad to help. Please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the result set into two parts, one for the pure date result, and the rest for 'ongoing' & 'N/A'. Combine them using `UNION`.

Which will be the query like this:

```
Select col1, col2 
From table 
where ... --condition to filter out those rows with real date
order by date 

UNION

Select col1, case when col2 ... then 'Ongoing' when col2 ... then 'N/A'
From table
where ... --condition to filter out those rows need to be replace with characters
--not necessary using `order by for this part`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the ORDER BY clause as follows:

```
SELECT MyDate FROM MyDateTable
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN MyDate IN ('n/a','Ongoing') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    MyDate
```